# Why is the Sigmoid function not displaying the line on the scatter plot?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently using the 'Sigmoid' function, which the 'cost' function uses in order to determine, where the line should be within the scatter plot diagram. However, upon output, the x and y arrays are outputted onto the scatter plot with the correct keys, but the line is absent from the diagram.

**The code that determines the theta is as follows:**

```
def loadTrgDf():
    train, test = proc.getTrainingData()

    # x derives from spouses and siblings
    x = train.iloc[:, 2:4]

    # y derives from the actual output
    y = train.iloc[:, 1]

    # Split and zeros
    initial_theta = np.zeros(x.shape[1])

    # Calculate the threta
    theta = opt.fmin_cg(cost, initial_theta, cost_gradient, (x, y))

    print(" ")
    print(theta)

    # Store for readability
    sibSpTheta = theta[0]
    parchTheta = theta[1]
```

**The findings are then plotted into a scatter graph here:**

```
    # Plot findings
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for index, row in train.iterrows():
        if row['Survived'] == 1:
            ax.scatter(row['SibSp'], row['Parch'], marker="+", c='green')
        else:
            ax.scatter(row['SibSp'], row['Parch'], marker="x", c='red', linewidth=1)

    plt.title("Survival Rate", fontsize=16)
    plt.xlabel("Spouses", fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel("Siblings", fontsize=14)

    plt.legend(["survived", "not survived"])

    plt.show()

    x_axis = np.array([x.min(), x.max()])
    y_axis = (-1 / 1) * (sibSpTheta * x_axis + parchTheta)
    ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, linewidth=2)
    fig
```

**The code below is used by the opt.fmin_cg function:**

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

def cost(theta, x, y):
    predictions = sigmoid(x @ theta)
    predictions[predictions == 1] = 0.5 # log(1)=0 causes division error during optimization
    error = -y * np.log(predictions) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - predictions)
    return sum(error) / len(y);

def cost_gradient(theta, x, y):
    predictions = sigmoid(x @ theta);
    return x.transpose() @ (predictions - y) / len(y)
```

**Values:**

```
   PassengerId  Survived  SibSp  Parch
77            78         0      0      0
748          749         0      1      0
444          445         1      0      0
361          362         0      1      0
576          577         1      0      0
27            28         0      3      2
232          233         0      0      0
424          425         0      1      1
785          786         0      0      0
...          ...        ...    ...    ...
```

x contains the IV's SibSp and Parch

y contains the DV survived

**This is the unexpected output:**

[image]

**This is the expected output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**
The line appeared! However, it's inaccurate.

[image]

Comment: Plz provide actual x and y values in your code rather than posting snapshots from which we can't copy the values

Comment: try to move `plt.show()` after `ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, linewidth=2)`

Comment: @Bazingaa Thank you, the line has appeared! However it seems to be a bit distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the plotting, but with the regression concept.

```
y_axis = (-1 / 1) * (sibSpTheta * x_axis + parchTheta)
```

This derives from the calculation that looks like this:

```
weights * features = weight0 + weight1 * feature1 + weight2 * feature2 + ...
```

You need to create a weight which corresponds to no feature value so this line becomes something that looks like this:

```
freeWeight = theta[0]
sibSpTheta = theta[1]
parchTheta = theta[2]

y_axis = (-1 / freeWeight) * (sibSpTheta * x_axis + parchTheta)
```

This can be done by creating an extra column which corresponds to no feature but has a dummy value when you splice your data frame. This process is called scaling.

Moving onto the `x` and `+` markers. You need to loop the `x` data frame. Not the full `train` data frame.